# CEdit in CDialog not working in Japanese and chinese language

Tags: visual-c++, fonts, mfc, chinese-locale, cedit

I have a unicode MFC Dialog application which has CEdit control. When i change the system language to Japanese/Chinese and enter Japanese or Chinese characters, I don't get EN_CHANGE or EN_UPDATE notification. The text goes to multiple lines. I get EN_CHANGE or EN_UPDATE if I do a ENTER from keyboard and text gets wrapped in a single line. I tried changing fonts from Dialogue resource; but still no luck.
Have you come across these kind of issues? Any clue or lead will be appreciated.

[image: Screen shot from my app]

-Sukhas

Comment: What is the LANGUAGE_ID in dialog resources file (.rc)? What are your project settings (character set)?

Comment: in the rc file, i am seeing the following entries.  #if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_JPN)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_JAPANESE, SUBLANG_DEFAULT
#pragma code_page(932)
#endif //_WIN32

Comment: Character set is Unicode.  Also i created the app after changing the language to Japanese.

Comment: Are you able to enter Japanese or Chinese characters in Notepad?

Comment: yes...I am able to.

Comment: It does look like a font problem or something similar

Comment: Run Spy++ and trap the messages when it works correctly.  Then, run it again for Japanese and trap the messages to see what the discrepancy is.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin, any specific font i need to use?

Comment: Use "MS Shell Dlg"